# load a page entirely at a time instead of one part after another

Tags: javascript

The following javascript appends the content to the end of the newly created paragraph as soon as it loads a json file successfuly. And since there's a fake time delay in `get` and `getSync` functions, I thought the page would load the story one chapter after another, but it's not. I have to wait for a while, then suddenly the whole story appeared instead of one part after another. Why?

I tried to debug the javascript. But when I executed the javascript line by line, the story appeared one paragraph after another, which was different when it was not debugged. I don't know why. Here is the code.

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Promises test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="network-fake">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Fake network delay</label>
  </div>
  <div class="story"></div>
  <svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="20" height="20">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="42" transform="rotate(-90,50,50)" />
  </svg>
  <script src="utils.js"></script>
  <script>
    try {
      var story = getJsonSync('story.json');
      addHtmlToPage(story.heading);

      story.chapterUrls.forEach(function(chapterUrl) {
        var chapter = getJsonSync(chapterUrl);
        addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
      });

      addTextToPage("All done");
    }
    catch (err) {
      addTextToPage("Argh, broken: " + err.message);
    }

    document.querySelector('.spinner').style.display = 'none';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### utils.js

```
var fakeSlowNetwork;

(function() {
  var lsKey = 'fake-slow-network';
  var networkFakeDiv = document.querySelector('.network-fake');
  var checkbox = networkFakeDiv.querySelector('input');

  fakeSlowNetwork = Number(localStorage.getItem(lsKey)) || 0;

  networkFakeDiv.style.display = 'block';
  checkbox.checked = !!fakeSlowNetwork;

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    localStorage.setItem(lsKey, Number(checkbox.checked));
    location.reload();
  });
}());

function spawn(generatorFunc) {
  function continuer(verb, arg) {
    var result;
    try {
      result = generator[verb](arg);
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
    if (result.done) {
      return result.value;
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(callback, errback);
    }
  }
  var generator = generatorFunc();
  var callback = continuer.bind(continuer, "next");
  var errback = continuer.bind(continuer, "throw");
  return callback();
}

function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

function get(url) {
  // Return a new promise.
  // We do all the work within the constructor callback.
  var fakeNetworkWait = wait(3000 * Math.random() * fakeSlowNetwork);

  var requestPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do the usual XHR stuff
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('get', url);

    req.onload = function() {
      // 'load' triggers for 404s etc
      // so check the status
      if (req.status == 200) {
        // Resolve the promise with the response text
        resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        // Otherwise reject with the status text
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    // Handle network errors
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    // Make the request
    req.send();
  });

  return Promise.all([fakeNetworkWait, requestPromise]).then(function(results) {
    return results[1];
  });
}

function getJson(url) {
  return get(url).then(JSON.parse);
}

function getSync(url) {
  var startTime = Date.now();
  var waitTime = 3000 * Math.random() * fakeSlowNetwork;

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('get', url, false);
  req.send();

  while (waitTime > Date.now() - startTime);

  if (req.status == 200) {
    return req.response;
  }
  else {
    throw Error(req.statusText || "Request failed");
  }
}

function getJsonSync(url) {
  return JSON.parse(getSync(url));
}

function getJsonCallback(url, callback) {
  getJson(url).then(function(response) {
    callback(undefined, response);
  }, function(err) {
    callback(err);
  });
}

var storyDiv = document.querySelector('.story');

function addHtmlToPage(content) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = content;
  storyDiv.appendChild(div);
}

function addTextToPage(content) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = content;
  storyDiv.appendChild(p);
}
```

story.json

```
{
  "heading": "<h1>A story about something</h1>",
  "chapterUrls": [
    "chapter-1.json",
    "chapter-2.json",
    "chapter-3.json",
    "chapter-4.json",
    "chapter-5.json"
  ]
}
```

chapter-1.json

```
{
  "chapter": 1,
  "html": "<p>Chapter 1 text: Cras sollicitudin orci ac velit adipiscing, ut faucibus urna auctor. Pellentesque in sem nec sem molestie malesuada. Sed aliquam mi sit amet sollicitudin luctus. Aenean quis tempus sem, in viverra metus. Maecenas sed urna bibendum, cursus lectus sed, ultricies risus.</p>"
}
```

`chapter-2.json` ~ `chapter-3.json` have the same format as `chapter-1.json`.